# duality quantum computing simulation

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, cirq

I am a starter of this quantum mostly new to quantum computing but I wonder if there is any option of simulating duality quantum computing in qiskit or IBM q or any other alternative way?

[Duality Quantum Computing and the efficient simulation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03200#:%7E:text=In%20this%20review%2C%20we%20will%20show%20that%20duality,precision%20for%20simulating%20systems%20with%20a%20sparse%20Hamiltonian.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.